# Install app which uses .dll with IExpress Wizard

Tags: c#, .net, iexpress

I have two applications which will be installed by a single executable. The problem I'm facing is that one of them uses a .dll. And whenever the IExpress package tries to run the first executable it says that the .dll could not be found, even tough I added the .dll inside and outside the package.

There is any way to make it work with IExpress, which has the required characteristics?

There is any alternative to my problem, as a similar software, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds vaguely similar to this question:

[Iexpress is extracting to %temp% folder... How do I prevent this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047030/iexpress-is-extracting-to-temp-folder-how-do-i-prevent-this)

As I mentioned in my answer, check: (1) is long file name (LFN) support enabled? and (2) is the `.dll` actually in the archive?

If checking those things doesn't resolve it, I would use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see which directories the executable is searching to locate the `.dll` file. It should ideally be looking in the extraction directory (eg `%temp%\IXP000.TMP`), since that's the *current directory* when the executable is running.

Of course there are several other utilities that do what IExpress does that you might try instead: [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/), [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/), [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) – just to name a few.