# Iexpress is extracting to %temp% folder... How do I prevent this?

Tags: iexpress

Basically I've binded two files, one of them works fine because it can be run from any directory on the computer, however the other one requires .DLL dependencies found in the folder that the binded file is in... However when you run the binded file (made in express) it extracts both the programs to the **%temp%** folder, so the program cannot find the .DLL dependencies and therefore doesn't work.

Is there anyway to make it extract the files into the directory it's being ran from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iexpress - extraction path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534699/iexpress-extraction-path)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already answered this question here:

[Iexpress - extraction path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534699/iexpress-extraction-path/13700281#13700281)

It's actually a bit of a pain, since the *current directory* while IExpress is running an install program is something like `%temp%\IXP000.TMP` and there's very little clue where it was originally started without reverse traversing the "process tree".

Having said that, the extraction location (eg `%temp%\IXP000.TMP`) should contain both the executable *and* the `.dll` there, so the DLL should be easy for the executable to find. You might check the usual suspects: (1) is long file name (LFN) support enabled? and (2) is the `.dll` actually in the archive? More info on another answer here:

[jar file not found iexpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096963/jar-file-not-found-iexpress/19131090#19131090)

Comment: do not answer with a link to a duplicate, select close -> duplicate and move on.