# jar file not found iexpress

Tags: jar, iexpress

I am using iexpress to make my .jar files into .exe files

for this I add the jar file(myjarfile.jar) and in run command box I type : java -jar myjarfile.jar

but after creating the .exe the cmd that is flashing says cannot find the jar file myjarfile.jar

can any body help me find what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test this, I built a simple `HelloWorld.jar` file (using [these instructions](http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.ca/2007/11/how-to-make-jar-file.html)) and tested it like so:

```
java -jar HelloWorld.jar
```

Then I made an IExpress package with it. The *Install program* was exactly the command I used above. This worked exactly as it should.

Two possible causes of the error:

1. In the IExpress wizard, there's a checkbox *Store files using Long File Name inside Package*. You should definitely select this option; ignore the warning that appears, as it applies to Windows 95/98. In the `.sed` file, this is:

   ```
   UseLongFileName=1
   ```
2. Check that the `.exe` actually contains `myjarfile.jar`. [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) will open the `.exe` and show you the archive contents. (IExpress `.exe` files are just a CAB file with a wrapper.) If the file is missing, then you'll need to check your `.sed` file to see what went wrong.

Comment: my problem was that my jar name was too long. So I renamed it with a shorter name